# Android Cucumber UI test problem with com.google.android.material

Tags: android, cucumber, android-espresso, material-components-android, gui-testing

I wrote a test scenario with the help of Cucumber and espresso and when I run the test it crashes wherever I use the com.google.android.material library.

For example :

com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout ,
com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

Error :

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line # in
> layout/fragment_layout: Error inflating class
> com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

Cucumber or espresso seems to have a problem with the material library.

I ran my test with this command :

> ./gradlew connectedMyFlavorAndroidTest -Pcucumber -Pscenario="My
> Scenario"

and it crashed wherever there was a material library in UI(xml layout).

Answer (score 0):

I just had to define R.style.Theme for the launchFragmentInContainer :)

> launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.Theme)